# How to get content of ARC Welder

Tags: android, web-crawler, apk

I'm using `ARC Welder` to run a `apk` on mu ubuntu. In the android program I have installed, there are lots of comments (more than 10000). I want to get all these comments from the app and process them, in other words I want to crawl ARC Welder.

Is it possible?